# I need to use Cross Reference Tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm new to C# programming and I'm starting to learn the MVC4 framework. I decided to just dive in with a small web app idea for a mentoring program. I've come to a problem with adding a mentee to the system. I wasn't able to provide a diagram of the table relationship that I need help with so here goes...

I have 3 tables:

**Address:**
address_id
address1
address2
city
......

**Mentee:**
mentee_id
first_name
middle_name
last_name
......

**Mentee_Address:**
mentee_id
address_id

Of course EF doesn't recognize the cross reference table so the Models class for Mentee
and Address:

*Mentee Class:*

```
public partial Class mentee
{
  public mentee()
  {
     this.addresses = new HashSet<address>();
  }

  public int mentee_id { get; set; }
  public string first_name { get; set; }
  public string middle_name { get; set; }
  public string last_name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<address> addresses { get; set; }
}
```

*Address Class:*

```
public partial Class address
{
  public address()
  {
     this.mentees = new HashSet<mentee>();
  }

  public int address_id { get; set; }
  public string address1 { get; set; }
  public string address2 { get; set; }
  public string city { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<mentee> mentees { get; set; }
}
```

In my create view, i'm trying to add the student and address record along with keeping the relationship intact with addresses and mentees. I've read that EF does this without actually updating the cross reference table Mentee_Address. If so can someone provide a detailed explanation, if not, i need a way of accessing the cross reference table so that it can be updated.

```
public ActionResult Create(ViewModels.MenteeViewModel menteeViewModel)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.mentees.Add(menteeViewModel.mentee);
    db.addresses.Add(menteeViewModel.address);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the relationship between `mentee` and `address` by adding the `address` to the `mentee.addresses` collection (or the other way around, it doesn't matter), like this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    menteeViewModel.mentee.addresses.Add(menteeViewModel.address);
    db.mentees.Add(menteeViewModel.mentee);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You don't need to add the `address` to the context explicitly in this example because it will happen automatically together with adding the `mentee`. The code will INSERT a new `mentee` to the database, a new `address` and a link record into the link table `Mentee_Address`. I'm not sure if you want to insert both `mentee` and `address`, but that is what your original code would do as well. My example above just adds the link record to the procedure.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the functionality i was looking for